# How to scrape multiple pages from the same website, without knowing full URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am just learning web scraping. I have the goal to retrieve info from the website which displays info about thousands of companies. In the website each company has its own page and the last element of URL is based on the company's name, for example:

https://rekvizitai.vz.lt/en/company/telesoftas/,
https://rekvizitai.vz.lt/en/company/devbridge_lt/

How would it be possible to scrape the website in this case without having the full list of the company names?

Comment: You can use simple [python with beautiful soup](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) or a framework like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Comment: A page like this often has listings pages where you can find the urls.  What have you attempted so far?  What hasn't worked?

Comment: @B.Adler I succeeded scraping data from one web page, looping through several web pages where URL changes based on some logic or index. 
However, I cannot find answer if it's possible to loop and scrape all the pages in the website without knowing full URL, like in this example.

Comment: @user9035132 https://rekvizitai.vz.lt/en/companies gets you the list of categories, from the list of categories you go to each category. From each category you get each url.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

names = ['telesoftas', 'devbridge_lt'] 

for name in names:
    html = requests.get(' https://rekvizitai.vz.lt/en/company/' + names)
```

Comment: What if I do not have the full list of the companies names? What would be the way to extract the data without the names list?

Comment: I would automate the process of searching for 5 categories, gathering all those company names, and repeat that for all categories. However that is a little too big of a task to have in one answer here on SO. After you have gathered all company names you can then proceed to scrabe all the company "sites" as I did in my answer.